# How to fix error "To run this application, you first must install one of the following version of the .Net Framework: v2.0.50727"?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-2.0

How do I fix the error that started popping up in a lot of applications:

> To run this application, you first must install one of the following
>   version of the .Net Framework: v2.0.50727.
>
> Would you like to download an install version v2.0.50727 of the .NET framework now?

Unfortunately, this is not as simple as just installing the .NET 2.0 runtime, because its already installed. If I run the recommended installers for .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5 SP1, it exits silently.

Events leading to problem:

- Installed SQL Server 2008 R2, which installs a toy version of Visual Studio 2008 that only deals with SQL specific projects.
- Uninstalled Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET 2.0 runtime?

Comment: You would only get this error if the .NET Framework 2.0 was not installed.

Comment: I would go ahead and reinstall everything you removed.

Comment: You uninstalled the VS-2008. So I think it also uninstalled the .net framework 2.0 too so try to download a standalone setup for this problem and try to install it then. Also check out event log if there is any valuable information you got.

Comment: Did you try reviewing Windows Event Viewer? It sometimoes offers interesting information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often seen situations similar to this related to corruption in the installed .Net installation. Martineau's suggestion of uninstalling and reinstalling the .Net is probably in the right ballpark.

You can get this error with the .Net still installed if the program throwing the error does not DETECT the installation. Uninstalling/reinstalling will help with that. After you've uninstalled the existing .Net package, you might read through this [article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/windows-installer-cleanup-utility-not-available/105b53a0-6f13-4823-b6fb-8e02eb7a4778?auth=1) about the most recent Cleanup utility from MS. If removal of some other application left corrupted system connections, you might need that cleanup in order to get your system back to rights.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you specified which version of Windows this relates to.

You can check the [Registry entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/framework/general/determine-dotnet-versions-service-pack-levels) to see if the values applications should be using to verify which versions of the .NET Framework are installed have been corrupted.

If you are using a version of Windows for which .NET Framework 2.0 cannot be uninstalled, this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222115514/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2012/03/28/10288684.aspx) has some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Installing .net 4.0 solved a similar issue for me before. I don't know why...